# URLLoader in actionscript 3 not using the same web session on some machines?

Tags: actionscript-3, urlloader

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain.net/registerVideo.php");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();    
vars.action = "insert";
vars.record = publishMode;
vars.name = streamName;
request.data = vars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(request);
```

The above client side code works for my machine(using the same web session),

but not working for some other machines.

Is this a known bug??

Comment: Watch the request with something like Live HTTP Headers, and tell us what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are testing this from the domain.net machine but loading from somewhere else.  If it is not working from another machine, you may have a security sandbox violation.  Try to add a crossdomain.xml file on your server with something like this to see if that fixes your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I wouldn't advise keeping this for production if it fixes your issue.  For more info, see this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply!But I already have added `crossdomain.xml`

Comment: And if it's security sandbox violation,there will be a dialog popping out,but there's no such dialog.

Comment: Shoot, that was my first guess given the symptoms.  That makes this a lot trickier then.  Actually I did see something somewhat similar to this when I was trying to upload files.  When I coded a straight servlet, it worked fine.  But when I used Spring, it did not work (though it did work from a basic upload web page).  Since you're on php, not sure that would be much help though.